# Does one fulfill p’ru u’rvu after one child

Tags: halacha, number, men-male, even-haezer, pru-urvu

Do men fullfill their obligation in their mitzvah of P’ru U’rvu after having one child? Or is the requirement to be fruitful and multiply fulfilled only after more children? If so, how many children is expected for a man to reproduce?